Creating a deadly "minimum altitude limit" in an airship setting
The world I'm building is basically Waterworld (1995) except instead of everyone living on the ocean because the planet is flooded, everyone lives in nomadic floating collections of improvised airships or clinging to exceedingly tall structures/geography.
I want there to be a hazard which prevents people from going down to low, forcing people to chase a "Goldilocks zone" where the air is thick and warm enough to live in yet also high enough to stay above the deadly hazard which blankets Earth below.
Here are the specific traits I'm looking for:

Needs to be planet-wide
Needs to be deadly. Individuals not wearing a fully independent air supply die within minutes
Should have "tides" or "undulations" where, due to air currents or other phenomenon, small patches of the Earth below occasionally temporarily become "safe" to go to or pockets of this hazard swell up and engulf normally safe altitudes
Needs to be "stable" over millennia timespans

Whatever it is, it needs to be reasonably conform to modern physics--this is a no magic setting. I don't need to explain how this happened (bonus points though!)
My current idea is a massive quantity of some extremely dense gas which displaces the regular atmosphere, such as Sulfur Hexafluoride, however I am unsure if (a) it would be resistant enough to withstand natural atmospheric perturbation to clearly form a layer and (b) if it would be "stable" over very long time periods.

Deadly minimum altitude limit: The Ground. Jokes aside, this is an interesting premise.

Where does people's food come from? An atmosphere that will suffocate humans will kill plants too, and farming on airships and mountain-tops won't support many people.

@JohnDallman That is not within the scope of the question

This is already a decently-fantastical situation. Without actual magic, it would be trivial to imagine an edible plant that, with basic nutrients and sunlight, grows very quickly. Of course the issue would be that the airship would be a closed system, so everything would have to be recycled until the Altitude Hazard allows for resource collection on the surface momentarily.

Please remember that we are not a brainstorming site. Open ended questions with many equally valid answers are not permitted. Do you have a specific idea? Is there a specific problem you have with that idea? Ask us about that. Don't ask us to build your world for you. You have that at the end of your post. Ask about that and only that.

Just don't explain it. Or explain it with absolute nonsense. Mad Max is a no-magic setting. The oceans are gone. "How, that's impossible, you'd have to build a space elevator and boost bazillions of tons of water to escape velocity!" "Because war or something." "But that's -" "VROOM VROOM WITNESS ME THAT'S HOW, BLOODBAG" "Aieeeee"

Double extra bonus points if you call the definitely not magical fog of death "The Climate Change".

Whatever you use, keep in mind that absolute altitude vs above ground altitude can be more than a mile different even in major cities.

@JohnDallmann: Not every gas will kill plants too. Take Carbon Mono or Dioxide for example. Plants do not need Oxygen to "breathe". They just need a source of anorganic substances.

Isn't this basically Venus?

@Antares - plants also respire similarly to animals they use oxygen at night. It's just that they generate more oxygen than they consume over all. Complex plants would not survive without oxygen.

Dan Simmons' The Rise Of Endymion has a planet T'ien Shan with similar characteristics; the surface is covered by toxic phosgene gas, and everyone lives high up in the mountains (featured on the cover). It's a major plot point and a nice (part of the) story I really liked.

Disease-carrying mosquitos maybe?  I went skydiving recently and I was pleasantly surprised at how all the annoying insects are only in the lowest 25 feet or so of the atmosphere near the ground. But above that, you're not going to get any mosquito bites.

Three words: literal lightning bugs.

Advanced yet messy gene editing technologies inadvertently caused the spread of toxin-producing plant life across the planet, requiring humans to retreat upwards. The toxin is gaseous, causing it to cover the Earth's surface, but also decomposes under UV light in just a few hours, preventing deadly concentrations from reaching too high into the atmosphere. This creates a sort of tide, where the toxin creeps upward at night, before being pushed back by the Sun during the day.

Unlike many other answers, this one allows people to still live on parts of the surface that are too cold and/or infertile for those toxic plants to grow. How big a part? Whatever the story needs!

I immediately thought of something very similar in the same vein of a gas since it has to be worldwide, but I just thought that since isn't classified as "hard science" you should make up a very heavy gas that sank and lingers near the surface... The problem is that it leaves less room for creativity because you can't really undo it (easily).
On the plus side of a heavy gas is that it makes it easier to float on, so you can use that as an excuse to hold much higher weights constantly in the air, if played correctly.

You are looking for Venus in real life.  There is a layer of the Venusian atmosphere about 50km up that is a comfortable temperature and pressure for human life.  As you start to go lower, the air pressure and temperature increases dramatically; go low enough and you're boiling in clouds of super-heated, highly-pressurized sulfuric acid.

Exactly. I read a book in the last few years based on Venus with people living in the clouds and in the "best" parts they could be outside unprotected for a little while but far down it was like going into the deep sea on Earth because of high pressure.

It does not even need to be Venus specifically, but any planet with a runaway greenhouse effect will work. It will actually be even better if it's farther from the sun than Venus because then your goldilocks altitude will have a higher air pressure making airships even more efficient.

Higher air pressure might make the ship more efficient, but it also means more danger; idk what the OP will consider 'too dangerous', so I aimed for standard temp and pressure.

Came here ready to write about Venus too and saw this answer.  The goldilocks temperature and pressure zone is at altitude.  But unfortunately, sulfuric acid, so...yeah.

I am not a toxicologist or a meteorologist or a volcanologist, but I do have a suggestion that meets all the criteria:
This world is blanketed in highly-active volcanos that constantly spew toxic gas
Specifically, they spew sulfur compounds like hydrogen sulfide, which are heavier than air, meaning that in large quantities they would aggregate on the surface rather than rising up to higher altitudes, and also flammable and highly toxic. One, the density of hydrogen sulfide in the lower atmosphere is so high that below a certain safety threshold, humans receive a lethal dose as the hydrogen sulfide density is above about 300 ppm, which is where severe adverse reactions start happening, and in a world powered by steam engines or nuclear reactors alike (tech level wasn't originally specified), it's generally not great if a highly-flammable gas starts infiltrating your airship.
Overall, I'd expect a lot of low-level eruptions happening pretty much constantly at least in one spot on the surface. The sulfides gradually built up over millennia after the Great Eruption began, and now the gases blanket the surface. This not only provides an entry point for your civilization, which most certainly didn't develop the airship before the wheel (this way, they once did inhabit the ground but now don't), but also provides a more-or-less physically reasonable explanation to why your upper atmosphere is mostly breathable while your lower atmosphere has gone to crap.
This satisfies all your requirements:

Needs to be planet-wide. - There are instances, like Io for example, of celestial bodies with very high volcanic activity across the whole planet. This world would be an extreme case of course, but it's not physically unreasonable.
Needs to be deadly. Individuals not wearing a fully independent air supply die within minutes. - If you don't bring an oxygen tank and an air filter with you, you'll be breathing in a lot of $\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{S}$, which is as mentioned quite toxic. It also causes skin/eye irritation, so Surfacedivers will probably be equipped with heavier clothing or even body-covering hazard suits as well.
Should have "tides" or "undulations" where, due to air currents or other phenomenon, small patches of the Earth below occasionally temporarily become "safe" to go to or pockets of this hazard swell up and engulf normally safe altitudes. - Occasionally, a local volcano goes into dormancy for a few weeks/months/years and stops spewing toxic sulfides. Winds will carry nearby toxins into the area, but if a particularly large volcano that originally toxified a large region stops erupting for a moment, the wind might clear out a patch of ground where the air is less toxic to humans. Conversely, if such a volcano undergoes an especially-violent eruption, the plumes can briefly extend into the otherwise-safe upper atmosphere. Once the plume's gases and ashes lose heat, however, they will of course come back down to the surface since those compounds and particles are heavier than air.
Needs to be "stable" over millennia. - Volcanism can last a very long time. Earth's volcanoes have been around for at least 850,000 years in some regions, and if we're talking about a world that's perhaps tidally heated or otherwise tormented by an especially-close moon or a gas giant primary, then we might expect that volcanism to be both more active and more permanent (see Io).

Naturally there are issues with this question (why has the whole atmosphere not been completely flooded by sulfides? how did all these volcanos come to be? why are they still going continuously after millennia), but it's functionally good enough. If you say that this world is highly volcanic and is constant belching toxic heavier-than-air gases into the lower atmosphere without it filtering very far upwards due to the relative lightness of oxygen and nitrogen compared to sulfur, the only people who are going to argue with you about it are people who weren't really that invested in your world to begin with.

This doesn't quite meet his requirements--namely, the quick death from being in the danger.  It's not going to have such a sharp threshold, nor be able to undulate.

Volcanoes are in general good candidates for spilling high amounts of any kind of lethal gases, like carbon mono-/dioxide and others. Does not necessarily need to be a highly reactive gas. Only one that is not breathable and can linger on the ground.

@LorenPechtel "H2S is immediately fatal when concentrations are over 500-1000 parts per million . . . ." See paper at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2850187/

Again, this is already a pretty fantastical scenario. It's hard to imagine a solution that instantly kills people below a certain altitude that also doesn't include some sort of magic or sci fi.

@MTA My problem is that if it's rapidly deadly at X meters why is it not slowly deadly at say X + 50 meters?  It's not all going to stay down there by the ocean, it will mix.

@LorenPechtel Totally agree, it's not a good candidate because it readily diffuses and it's detectable at extremely low concentrations, making for a miserable-smelling world. Just wanted to point out how rapidly deadly it is in sufficient concentrations.

Of course this is far from a perfect solution, but without introducing something truly-fantastical it's the best I could come up with. Perhaps the atmospheric pressure is higher which would make the boundary between deadly and safe thinner, or perhaps the agitation is lower so the diffusion is reduced; I'm sure there's a solution to this problem that fits all the parameters, this is just the best I could do.

I've done something like this in a setting for my latest D&D campaign.  The atmospheric pressure and temperature at sea level is something like 19 ATM, and the temperature is around 120°C, though water doesn't boil due to the pressure.  At those temperatures and pressures, people would cook alive, and if the temperature didn't get them, they'd die of Nitrogen narcosis.
In this world, people live at an altitude of around 25km above sea level, where the air temperature and pressure is earth-normal.
How would you get something like this?  Just add more air, and have a bit of a greenhouse effect.  Of course, this scenario begs the question that if ground-level air is so dangerous, how does anything like plants and animals live there?  In my world, there is land magically pinned in mid-air at around 25km ASL, but the OP's world is physics-based, and that sort of land just isn't going to fly.
Basically, with such a world, you have the same problems as the movie Waterworld... how do you feed everyone?  Where are your other resources coming from?  It seems to me that like Waterworld, this is no more than a scenario where a small group of people are trying to stave off their inevitable demise.

No fire resistance?  And note that they would also die of oxygen toxicity.  That surface is way above the CNS oxygen toxicity safety limit but I'm having no luck figuring out the danger level.

@LorenPechtel Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity.  Oxygen toxicity begins from 0.5atm PP, which in 20% O2 air would occur from 2.5atm.  At 19atm, you'd have 3.8atm PP O2, which would be pretty darn toxic.  Only the Warforged are going that low without protection.

That page has a lot more discussion of it than I saw elsewhere but doesn't quantify the danger.  Which pretty much says we don't know.

@LorenPechtel People will over time produce more or less red blood cells allowing us to adapt to significantly increased or decreased O2 levels.  You may end up with people who have much fewer red blood cells to prevent their body from taking in too much O2.

Nanites
Personally, if I were writing in your universe I'd leave the phenomenon unexplained because that's far more intriguing imo, but the only way I see to keep the hazard highly localized to the surface and not mix to asphyxiating concentrations in the rest of the stratosphere is to give it some agency.
Perhaps clouds or filaments of extremely small robots just happened and now all life bound to the Earth's surface has been consumed. They localize to the ground, because, well, perhaps the sky just isn't as useful as the enormous chunk of metals and minerals below.
When aircraft/airships venture too low, these filaments have a tendency to detect and enswarm them.
The nanite swarms leave certain areas that have been stripped to low concentrations of useful materials until it becomes economic again to mine in that area further.

I like the idea of leaving it undefined, and just giving it a name ("the Red Clouds", "Haze", whatever). Like "Thread" in Anne McCaffery's Pern series.

Mix bots with "AI is a crapshoot" and have a bunch of robots tasked with "protecting the environment" and choose to do it in a way that isn't what was intended. Maybe the  local AI needs to reboot occasionally and takes a few hours to get over the cyber hangover?

Nanites violate the OP's explicit statement about modern technology or magic. The OP states "it needs to be reasonably conform to modern physics--this is a no magic setting." Nanites like you suggest aren't possible today and it isn't sure if they are even possible to the extent you've suggested. How are they powered world wide? How do they move? How would an airship that has strayed too low and received nanites not be dead regardless of time spent low, as the nanites would start to multiply as they consume the airship? It is a theoretical solution that might never be possible.

@Trioxidane I won't argue that my answer isn't a step-in for magic. As I said in it, I don't think you're going to get a highly localized phenomenon with pure density differential and inversion layers, and one hugging the surface closely enough to permit a worldwide "habitable zone" in the sky. I think it needs some agency to accomplish OP's goals, and the only logical and remotely science-based answer possible in my mind were nanites.

Also, if OP runs with nanites, who said anything about immediate self-replication on contact with an airship? Even if, why would that be an issue? The robots prefer to hug the surface because beneath it is where all the usefulness of Earth is. If this were my setting I'd specialize the robots. The "filaments" commonly seen in the skies are perhaps purposed for transport. Self-replication isn't part of their function. Etc.

A worldwide smog
The meteorology presented here is speculative, but probably not very realistic. Still, it sounds at least a bit believable to me as a layperson.
The surface of your planet was originally covered with an abundant vegetation, building up over time rich and omnipresent layers of peat, lignite and coal. At some point in time, these started to burn underground, and the resulting smouldering completely got out of control and spread to every part of the world. For now, the amount of oxygen near the ground is still high enough to keep it going, but a thick layer of smoke, carbon monoxide, sulfuric acid and other toxic gases has amassed.
All these gases are trapped in the lower parts of the athmosphere because of an athmospheric inversion: at the top of the smog layer, the sunlight is reflected, leading to low temperatures near the ground and higher temperatures in the clear air above. This blocks the exchange of air between the layers and further aggrevates the problem of pollution below.
This is exactly the scenario known from the classic London smog, but on a worldwide level. While in London the bad air at some point just got blown away, that cannot happen on your planet because the inversion layer has stabilized worldwide.
Still, there are temporary disturbances in the layer. Fire flaring up in a place below would lead to a local column of hot gases piercing through into the higher athmosphere, while at the same time sucking in air from the surrounding area, so that conditions at some distance actually improve. But these are only localised effects not able to destabilize the planet-wide system.

Another answer proposed vulcanism as the source of toxic gases. I thought about it, but then dismissed it because of two reasons: Vulcanic eruptions are often violent and hot events of impressive magnitude that rise matter up into the highest reaches of the athmosphere. I am a bit in doubt that goes together with a stable inversion. In the same vein, if a volcano grows to be a high mountain, its flanks may also reach up into the upper layer.
In other words: the planetary surface needs to be reasonably flat, have no large oceans, and the gas-producing events need to be of a mostly non-eruptive nature for this to work.

In Naughty Dog and Sony's The Last Of Us, a kind of fungus called cordiceps evolves to infect humans. While the videogame series and TV show have some fantastic elements, there is a slight scientific basis for that.
Kurzgesagt has a video on fever. At the 0:52.mark, it says that most cold blooded animals' insides are infected with fungi, but humans are practically immune to that. This is true. The Last Of Us TV show then goes on a tangent to say that due to climate change, fungi are adapting to higher temperatures and thus cordiceps makes a leap from arthropods to humans.
So, considering:

Here are the specific traits I'm looking for:



Needs to be planet-wide


The Last Of Us is about a global zombie epidemic, only the zombies are people infected by mind controlling fungi rather than being undead.
In your case you just need people to die, so you can say some biological agent produces a toxin that kills humans really quick.


Needs to be deadly. Individuals not wearing a fully independent air supply die within minutes


In both the games and TV show, people must wear masks when in unsafe areas because if they breath spores they turn into biological zombies within 24 hours. Taylor it to your needs to make death come faster if you breath it.


Should have "tides" or "undulations" where, due to air currents or other phenomenon, small patches of the Earth below occasionally temporarily become "safe" to go to or pockets of this hazard swell up and engulf normally safe altitudes


In the case of fungal spores, they can be carried by wind, so yeah.


Needs to be "stable" over millennia timespans


Biological hazards are perfect for this because nature exists in an equilibrium.

Alternatively, if you want something more elaborate than a gas, you can have something that likes to eat humans. In a mangá series called Biomeat, the Earth is infested with small animals that eat humans. They are killed by sunlight, so people are safe while outside by day. Tayloring it to your story, you can have creatures of any size that will attack and devour humans on sight. If they are small like spiders then the suit is not to protect you from breathing it, it is to protect you from having your skin chewed on. Kinda like land crabs are usually "immune" to ants but once the little buggers find an opening the crustacean is toast. And the undulations are caused by migratory currents.

Hydrogen Sulfide
For some unknown reason, the world below has been flooded with significant concentrations of hydrogen sulfide. Maybe intense lava flows, or some underground runaway effect has caused a massive overflow. Maybe there was a major industrial accident that caused a massive over-production.
The gas itself is dense, so without a significant concentration it won't rise too high - and it can be detected, even using primitive tools once people realized the connections. Additionally, it fits the criteria of being deadly.
Large concentrations of it might even be directly affected by the tides, it would get pushed around by air currents and flow creating artificial "waves".
One example of it's use was in Dr. Stone, where they created a method of using silver to detect the effects and primitive gas masks to survive it - a person in this environment would absolutely need to carry their own oxygen supply.

See my answer - my suggestion was that extreme volcanic activity results in perpetual $\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{S}$ clouds. (+1)

Gas that kills humans & animals and does not affect plants.

Disclaimer: Well, turns out, plants do indeed breathe Oxygen. My assumption is therefore not totally correct. At least, I do not know if plants would be able to extract Oxygen from O3, NO, NO2, etc. I leave the answer here for inspirational purposes. But I am inclined to delete it.

Gas canditates:

Ground-level Ozone (O3)
Carbon Monoxide (CO)
Carbon Di-Oxide (CO2) (ground-level accumulation!)
(There might be others as well, this list is not exhaustive)

Generally: Any gas that has a higher density than Oxygen (O2) and nitrogen (N2) (aka our "air") would sink to the ground over longer periods of time. Like a mixture of oil and water: The less dense oil will end up swimming on top, given enough time and being left undisturbed.
Problem is, that CO is almost equal in weight to the other gases in the air and also winds (convection) will stir up the gases constantly. But as the world changes, maybe temperatures and the general atmosphere composition also changed and the mixing of gases is lowered (see Turbopause for example).
Interesting properties:

The gas candidates, like many other gases, are transparent and especially those are also odorless. Therefore dubbed "silent killers". They can be detected by birdies in a cage falling from their poles or by technical equipment, though.

They are also not explosive (but might be burnable under certain conditions).

Since everything that is not Oxygen is not breathable, any human being or animal will suffocate to death within minutes, albeit so slowly that they just get tired (noting nothing special), then collapse (too late) and then suffocate (to death). Not like as you would imagine a very notably suffocation "under water".

High amounts of Nitrogen, Nitrogen-oxides (N2, N2O2, NO2) or other bonds (sulfur, carbon, hydrogen mainly)  could also be good candidates. But their properties vary: density (too light), explosiveness (extra dangerous), color (brownish) and smell (like rotten eggs) can be obvious hints.



Might not be true, see disclaimer:

Plant-Life remains largely unaffected.

Plant-life: Plants are not dependent on breathable air. They need to be able to do photosynthesis. The main ingredient which cannot be left out is a decent amount of (sun-) light (and warmth).
There is also need for a supply of anorganic substances of which organic substances can be build from. In our atmosphere these components are mainly cabon dioxide (CO2) and water (H2O). But either-or and any other would also do. Other nutritions are beneficial for expanded growth and forming of edible parts like fruits etc. but not entirely necessary by every form of plant-life.

The scenario can still have agriculture (inside green-houses). Either by "agricultural islands" on the ground or on mountaintops - given temperature etc. is okay.
Sources of those gases:

Ozone (O3) (an isotope of Oxygen) is formed by extended amounts of sun-light (UV-light or UV-radiation) that is causing Oxygen (O2) in the atmosphere to form "triplet" bindings (O3). Ozone can accumulate on ground-level as well as in the upper atmosphere (Ozone layer).
Best candidates would be global warming, climate changing effects. Meaning slow processes that built up over time and are now too strong too sustain human-/animal-life. A violent solar eruption (solar wind) might be tempting to burn away atmospheric protection layers and mess up earth's magnetic field, but this would also lead to so much UV-radiation that plant life would also be affected (severe droughts). Maybe a full loss of the upper Ozone layer would be sufficient already.

Carbon Monoxide (CO) is the product of incomplete burning. Meaning something is burned with too little Oxygen available, so CO2 (Carbon Di-Oxide) cannot be formed and CO (Carbon Mono-Oxide) is formed instead.
Best candidates are global burning of wood, coal, oil, gas, methane etc (all the stuff we need for "heating", contains carbon). Which can have a multitude of sources from "war" to "volcanic activity" to "asteroid impacts" to "zombicalypse / pathogens" - leading to death of so many people that nobody is able to control the wild fires anymore or they are overwhelmingly abundant anyways.


Counter-Measures:

Of course, oxygen tanks like fire fighters, scuba divers or astronauts have. Also available in most medical facilities for patients needing to breathe (pure) oxygen.

Early warning systems ("canary in a coal mine", technical devices)

Atmospheric "anomalies" causing wind etc. to clear out areas and mix in so much oxygen from upper layers that air is breathable for a (extended or short) period of time.


Want to know more?

Article: Dangerous Gases in Mining Activity
NASA: Global CO Levels
YouTube-Search: Carbon Monoxide Poisoning


please leave the answer. +1 for listing carbon dioxide, which would've been my answer otherwise. CO2 eruptions have killed entire villages, there are caves full of animal bones because CO2 accumulates in them... heavier than (mixed) air, regular physics, deadly, but survivable with equipment. It checks all the boxes.

I'm going to go with constant thunderstorm activity.
On this world, either an alternate-universe Earth or a colonized extrasolar planet, everyone lives in airships because the ground is constantly scoured by powerful thunderstorms occurring beneath a uniform cloud layer. Dirigibles simply can't be reinforced enough to protect them from this kind of weather while remaining lighter-than-air, so if your ship dips below the cloud cover, you're pretty screwed and pretty quickly.
If you happen to survive the fall to the surface, most of the world's surface is ocean, and treading water in 20 foot swells is why the real world has a US Coast Guard (and it's amazing their rescue stats are as good as they are even in a world where it isn't constantly storming). The very few crags of solid land are little better; nothing grows under this constant deluge, so the scattered landmasses are rain-smoothed rock, with no shelter, no food, no light, no warmth, and nobody coming to your rescue. Whether you actually last a minute or a month, you're dead as soon as you're lost sight of beneath the clouds.
Even staying well above this layer, your ship may have to dodge "thunderheads" that can blow up from underneath in minutes to form looming towers of "oh hell no", with even higher winds, massive hailstones, and cyclonic wind currents up to and including EF-6 and EF-7 tornadoes (yes, I realize the Enhanced Fujita Scale only goes to 5). These are predictable to a point, and most ship captains steer their blimps well away from areas where conditions even favor a thunderhead, to say nothing of an active one.
Despite the danger, the wind currents further out from these storms are useful for getting around the planet in a hurry, much as storms at sea can be a blessing in disguise for a sailing ship trapped in a doldrum. So, the very brave and very crazy (often co-located in the same captain) will "surf" these storms, riding the leading edge toward their destinations. The ones that get it right shave days or weeks off delivery times and earn fat bonuses for captain and crew. The ones that get it wrong are never seen again.

Frameshift:
Archer fish.
Yeah, the real thing has a range of a few feet and an attack power adequate for bugs.  Let's scale it up.  It's a big fish that can leap and squirt a neurotoxin at birds.  But it's not an apex predator, there's something that hunts it.  You can safely descend even to the water's surface if one of those hunters is down there.
It's not going to give you a very big danger zone but the question only specifies a danger zone, not it's size.

Does it have to be earth, or may it be some colonized planet?
A larger planet could simple have a much thicker atmosphere. Oxygen is toxic when it is too dense. Divers therefore use breathing gas with very little oxygen at great depths. This planet may simply have too much air.  Plants still make oxygen, locally adapted animals may live down there. People with breathing equipment may go down to get food and the stuff needed to maintain the airships.
Adding too much oxygen to earth's atmosphere may be possible too, if it need to be earth. Milennia meteors containing mostly oxygen, perhaps.

Flawed navigation equipment
Every airship should have navigational equipment. In this suite there can be many sensors that should keep it flying safely. Each airship came standard with these sensors. However, your world is not what it was. This messes with the sensors and is why some fail under or above a certain altitude. This causes an increasing overcorrection of the anti-crash system, which leaves pilots a few minutes to get out of there before the airship is essentially scuttled.
The reason that everyone has such a system is because they are bundled within the navigation hardware. The sensors that cause the failing under that altitude are required for normal flight, and thus can't be tampered with. Flying without the hardware is practically suicide. People are stuck between a rock and low altitude and must make the best of it.
Example: Boeing 737 MAX
The Boeing 737 MAX had a fatal flaw. A single sensor was responsible for checking something like if the plane was level. It could fail, and without redundant sensors the output would be thought as fact. The automated systems would try to correct the flight. Initially the pilot can compensate, but the systems will increase the correction until it can't be compensated by the pilot. This has resulted in several crashes and many dead.

I dont see how this answers the question, if you are just answering the Title, then it kinda makes sense - but the author specified they want something to exist on the planet surface to make inhabiting it deadly.

@TheDemonLord that I find an opinion. The hazard being a gas is heavily suggested, but the requirement is 'a hazard'. It is planet wide, deadly in minutes, can have 'tides and undulations' according to the weather, is stable over long times, and conforms to modern physics. Nowhere is stated 'on the surface'. That word isn't even present in the question. There are further hints that it is a gaseous threat hanging low what the OP wants, but I see no reason to stray from suggestions. Sometimes the best answers are not what the question initially hints at.

@Trioxidane "... A deadly hazard that blankets the Earth" sounds like something on the surface to me. Personally I think your answer is a bit silly because if some sort of global technical disruption in airships like this occurred, then, well, they're airships. I'm sure someone (the entirety of human civilization being extant in your scenario) can concoct a rescue operation. (And if not then every airship and aircrew die in the near future.) This situation does not last for millennia like OP listed.

While I agree, that sometimes thinking outside the box is more creative than following the suggestions, I see a major problem: It is still possible to reach the planet's surface without being affected by anything. Just think of a small airplane flown by hand without instruments. Or a huge gas filled balloon, slowly letting off gas until reaching the surface. Or just a long rope and a container full of people at the end being lowered. Even if a "magnetic field anomaly" could account for the failing instruments easily, the landing is not prevented by that entirely (thus, it is not "deadly").

@BMF it being silly according to you is fine. However, the blankets the Earth is merely your perception. I read it as that it needs to occur everywhere on Earth. Though I've been surprised that 'nanites' goes so easily. Mine is plausible, if 'silly' according to you. Nanites is simply techno magic, something we are not even sure is possible on such a scale and not possible with modern technology. This is explicitly forbidden by the op: 'it needs to be reasonably conform to modern physics--this is a no magic setting.'

@Trioxidane: Maybe update your answer with a different title and focus the text more on the circumstance that "something" influences the navigational instruments and use the plane as an example, not the primary focus. That is just a suggestion, my opinion that this is not "deadly enough" still holds. Maybe you have ideas to increase the danger-level with some other effects?

@Trioxidane I can see and understand your perception of "blanket." Although it's not mine, I think it's still valid. The only thing I found "silly" was how marginal the problem was. There's precedent for this type of problem, and yeah you could push it to a global crisis, but it's not reaching the scope OP envisioned as I understand it. They want something bad to happen to the entire Earth (a la Waterworld), not simply a few planes and blimps but literally everything else is fine. It's a completely different story you're painting here.

This answer is completely incongruous to the information specified in the question: "everyone lives in nomadic floating collections of improvised airships or clinging to exceedingly tall structures/geography", "Individuals not wearing a fully independent air supply die within minutes", and "Needs to be "stable" over millennia timespans".
